# テザリング中　githubコマンド　アクセスできない

Tags: github, ssh

通常のWi-Fi(ホテルや自宅のWi-Fi)を使用してる時はgit pullやpushコマンドは問題ないのですがテザリングやポケットWi-Fiの時だけpush、pullコマンドを実行するとずっとローディングのまま動かなくなります。

ping 8.8.8.8は問題なく動きます。

githubのsshは設定済みです。

通常のwifiではssh接続時下記ログが表示されます。

```
Hi USERNAME! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not
> provide shell access.
```

Comment: 使用しているプロトコル (ssh / http) は何ですか？
プロトコルを変えるとどうなりますか？
他の git サーバーや ssh サーバーへのアクセスはどうなりますか？

Comment: ブラウザから github.com へのアクセスは可能な状態ですか？

Comment: ブラウザからはアクセス可能です

Comment: .ssh/config に「IPQoS cs1」を追加するとどうでしょう？（追加の仕方は「IPQoS cs1」で検索してみてください）

Comment: 追加しても変わらないですね。。。

Answer (score 1):

コメントでも少し触れられていますが明示的には言われていないので…

[Testing your SSH connection](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/testing-your-ssh-connection)に従い、ssh単体での接続を確認してください。これでつながらないのであれば、gitやgithubはあまり関係なく、ssh接続が許可されていない環境という可能性が出てきます。
ブラウザーで https://github.com/ に接続可能なのであれば、素直にssh接続ではなくhttps接続に切り替えることも検討してください。

P.S. ちなみに[デザリングはKDDIの登録商標](https://getnews.jp/archives/112136)です（でした）。